# Filter from one Data Query to Another

Tags: sql, cognos-11

I have a two page report with a separate query for each page. Page one is orders due in from suppliers and the other page is order transaction history form suppliers (i.e receipts/issues).

My aim is to have page two only return the transaction history for part numbers still outstanding from the supplier and not the history for all receipts/issues.

For example page one returns two part numbers still outstanding from the supplier and the page two only showing the transaction history for the two part numbers returned on page one only. I don't want to see the transaction history for any part number not listed on page one.

How do I create a cross query filter in COGNOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

It would very much depend on whether your model has been properly modelled but it should be not particularly difficult to open the query and add a filter which filters by those transactions which are still outstanding.

For example, this list report has been filtered by a dimension which is not in the report but is in the query.

Since you already know what transactions are outstanding, it should be possible to add an appropriate filter to the query.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for delay, works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It sounds like Page 1 uses query 1 and page 2 uses query 2

- Query 1 is for page 1 (orders due in from suppliers)
- Query 2 is transaction history for items

Instead, create an inner join, joining the 2 queries will get a 3rd query
The join should be down to the item level.  Have page 2 use this query 3

- Query 3 will only show transaction history that is joined to orders due from suppliers